# To find the determinant in this question

Tags: determinant

Given $A$ by $4×4$ non singular matrix and $B$ be matrix obtained from A by adding to its third row twice the first row .Then $det(2A^{-1}B)$ is

$A:2$

$B:4$

$C:8$

$D:16$

I cannot think anything about this question .Any hints to get started

Comment: negative vote for what ?

Comment: The answer indicated as correct isn't. Look at a simple case explicitly. What is the simplest non-singular matrix?

Comment: @DanielFischer 1.i stated as per my textbook . 2.i didnt get ur point

Comment: Not the first time in history that a textbook is wrong. Look at a simple case to convince yourself that the indicated answer is wrong. Use known properties of determinants to obtain the correct answer.

Comment: Hint: take $A=I$ and see what is going on.

Comment: @Martigan Taking A=I Answer is 2

Comment: $2A^{-1}B=2I$ when $A=I$. So $2I$ is a matrix with four numbers $2$ all in the diagonal. What is its determinant? You should write the matrix explicitely or read again the determinant definition.

Comment: @Martigan Ah , my carelessnes .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $A=|R_1R_2R_3R_4|$. Then $B=|R_1R_2(R_3+2R_1)R_4|$. Here $|B|=|A|$ because we know that if we add any scalar multiple of some row of an determinant to another row, the value of the determinant remains same.

Now $|CD|=|C||D|$ for any square matrices $C, D$ of same order. By this we have
$$|2A^{-1}B|=2^4 |A^{-1}||B|=16|A|^{-1}|B|=16$$ since $|A|=|B|$.

Comment: how have u taken $2^{2}$ outside .Is it twice the $A^{-1}$ or just a constant.

Comment: The matrix is of rank $4$.

Comment: Rather I write this: If $A$ is square matrix of order $n\times n$ then for any scalar $c$ we shall have $|cA|=c^n |A|$.

Comment: @AnjanDebnath Thanks i became really optimistic at the end

Comment: @godonichia you are most welcome.